# Getting the error "socket.io not found"

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [socket.io: Failed to load resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653237/socket-io-failed-to-load-resource)

I have a server already running on **http://localhost:4250**

I have socket.io directory, which I have downloaded from the socket.io github.

and I am trying to connect to server like:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and how I connect to server:

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4250');

  socket.on('connect', function (data) 
  {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });

</script>
```

I am getting these errors:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

and

```
ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

I have already tried everything I know, so I don't know what to do now.

Thank you!

Comment: It can't load your `socket.io.js` javascript file. Check the path and make sure the file exists.

Comment: the file is in /lib directory but its getting called by index.js I think. Thats where I am confused.

Comment: And I am using all codes from the http://socket.io

Comment: Show code where you "add" socket.io

Comment: I have updated my question. And all in the same directory index.html and socket.io directory.

Comment: I think I need Node.js to run socket.io?

Comment: but how can I run socket.io in apache server then?

Comment: Probably using something like this: http://ronenagranat.blogspot.com/2011/02/apache2-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs.html

Comment: socket.io is a node package - you need to run it from a node app and when your node app listens to a socket, it automatically exposes the socket.io script in that url.

Answer (score 2):

### **The Issue**

- by adding `http://localhost:4250` before the rest of the source in the link tag (for socket.io) solves this problem. This is apparently due to the way the network binds ports to localhost, however I will try to find some more information on the cause;

### **What to change:**

---

**Making socket.io behave:**

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

should be change to

`<script src="http://localhost:4250/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

---