# socket.io + express networkerror: 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [socket.io: Failed to load resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653237/socket-io-failed-to-load-resource)

A simple express + socket.io hellow world app seems doesnt work, i keep getting

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http:// localhost:3002/socket.io/socket.io.js"

Anyone know this issue?

code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.configure(function () {
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.listen(3002);


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my:'data' });
});
```

Comment: ["The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

Comment: Yes, but whats wrong with the code that cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your Socket.IO server is listening on port `3002`, but you connected to:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

which by default uses standard port `80`. Try this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002');
```

Also you will probably have to change `localhost` to the IP of your machine.

**Side note:** If you are running Express Server and Socket.IO server on the same port, then you can simply do:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply sir! I dont think theres a different between using localhost or my IP? Alose i've tried your fix, still getting 404.

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe this is because you fired server listening after socket listening? Put this line: `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` after `app.listen(3002);`. That's the last idea I have. :)

Comment: Make sure you aren't reloading a cached page with the old portless URL.