# Socket.io.js returns 404 on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to create a chat app following [the tutorial on socket.io's website](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/). I've got it working on my local machine, but now I'm trying to upload it to an OpenShift Server.

In my app, I have the line:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

On my local machine, it loads fine, but on my server, it returns a 404 error. I thought that my `node_modules` might not be loading at first, but after shh-ing into the server and checking, I see they are present.

My dependencies in my `package.json` are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^3.4.8",
    "socket.io": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

There are many different questions on here about getting a 404 error from socket.io and I've gone threw many of them them attempting to solve this issue, with no progress.  Including changing the `script` src to:

```
http://app-domain.rhccloud.com
http://app-domain.rhccloud.com:8000
http://app-domain.rhccloud.com:8080
ws://app-domain.rhchloud.com:
```

Most of the suggestions aren't specific to an OpenShift server so I figured I'd ask specifically about it.

If needed, here's my `server.js`:

```
#!/bin/env node

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(port,ip,function() {
    console.log('listening');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('chat message',function(msg) {
        io.emit('chat message',msg);
    });

});
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did try all of these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653237/socket-io-failed-to-load-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
server.listen(port,ip,function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

not `app.listen`.